# Biblatex ambiguous citations aren't ambiguous - they have different years

Tags: biblatex

I'm a bit annoyed with the typesetting of citations that biblatex deems "ambiguous". In the following example, I have two papers with the same first author, but a different second author in two different years. When citing in the main text, the second author is included before "et al", since biblatex deems these references to be ambiguous. However, the references were published in different years, so I cannot see why these are ambiguous. Is it possible to get these citations referenced using only the first author?

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[hyperref,style=authoryear,natbib=true,maxbibnames=10,maxcitenames=2,useeditor=false,url=false,useprefix,giveninits=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{ref.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{jobname.bib}
@book{author_book,
title = {Book's title},
author = {Author, Some and Better, Some and Cetter, Some},
location = {The City},
publisher = {Publisher},
date = {2005},
}
@book{author_book2,
title = {Book's title},
author = {Author, Some and Getter, Some and Cetter, Some},
location = {The City},
publisher = {Publisher},
date = {2006},
}
\end{filecontents}

\bibliography{jobname}
% \bibliography{ref}

\begin{document}
Hello world \citet{author_book} \citet{author_book2}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

By default `biblatex` only considers the author (or more correctly the `labelname`) list to determine whether or not a citation is ambiguous. The year does not play a role. So even though the entries in the example are not ambiguous if you take the year into account, `biblatex` will still disambiguate them, because the name lists alone are ambiguous.

With

```
uniquelist=minyear,
```

`biblatex` will only disambiguate name lists if they would be ambiguous within the same year.

With

```
uniquelist=false,
```

name lists are never disambiguated.

See also p. 70 (documentation of the `uniquelist` option) and §4.11.4 *Name Disambiguation*, esp. §4.11.4.2 *Lists of Names (`uniquelist`)*, pp. 324-326, of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, maxbibnames=10, maxcitenames=2, uniquelist=minyear]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{author_book,
  title     = {Book's title},
  author    = {Author, Some and Better, Some and Cetter, Some},
  location  = {The City},
  publisher = {Publisher},
  date      = {2005},
}
@book{author_book2,
  title     = {Book's title},
  author    = {Author, Some and Getter, Some and Cetter, Some},
  location  = {The City},
  publisher = {Publisher},
  date      = {2006},
}
@book{uthor_book,
  title     = {Book's title},
  author    = {Uthor, Anne and Better, Some and Cetter, Some},
  location  = {The City},
  publisher = {Publisher},
  date      = {2018},
}
@book{uthor_book2,
  title     = {Book's title},
  author    = {Uthor, Anne and Getter, Some and Cetter, Some},
  location  = {The City},
  publisher = {Publisher},
  date      = {2018},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\textcite{author_book,author_book2}

\textcite{uthor_book,uthor_book2}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Author et al. (2005) and Author et al. (2006)//Uthor, Better, et al. (2018) and Uthor, Getter, et al. (2018)]

Comment: **Remark (+1):** For me `uniquename=minyear` throws an error (`! Package biblatex Error: Option 'uniquename=minyear' invalid.`), only **`uniquelist = minyear` works**.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Ugh. Thanks for pointing out the typo. Should be fixed.