# BibLaTeX uses multiple authors in citation although the references have different years

Tags: biblatex, citing, multiple-citations

I use BibLaTeX for managing citations. However, inline citations with three or more authors sometimes use more than one author, although these references have different years, and thus, can be distinguished.

I give you an MWE to make my issue clear:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,mincitenames=1,maxcitenames=2,giveninits=true,uniquename=mininit]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@article{Test2018,
    author = {Human, B and Person, P and Somebody, B},
    journal = {Journal of Journals},
    number = {1},
    pages = {1--8},
    title = {qwerty},
    volume = {1},
    year = {2018}
}
@article{Test2019,
    author = {Human, B and Random, R and Person, P},
    journal = {Journal of Papers},
    number = {1},
    pages = {1--8},
    title = {asdasd},
    volume = {1},
    year = {2019}
}
@article{Two2019,
    author  = {First, Stephan and Second, Robert},
    journal = {Journal of Research},
    number = {1},
    pages = {3--5},
    title = {A Title},
    volume = {1},
    year = {2019}
}

@article{Three2019,
    author  = {Uno, Alpha and Second, Beta and Third, Gamma},
    journal = {Journal of Stuff},
    number = {1},
    pages = {3--5},
    title = {Another Title},
    volume = {1},
    year = {2019}
}
\end{filecontents} 

\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

\begin{document}

This is a text with \autocite{Test2018} and \autocite{Test2019}. 

This is a two authors citation \autocite{Two2019}.

This is an unrelated citation with three authors \autocite{Three2019}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

*Expected output*:

```
This is a text with (Human et al. 2018) and (Human et al. 2019).
This is a two authors citation (First and Second 2019).
This is an unrelated citation with three authors (Uno et al. 2019).
```

*Actual output*:

```
This is a text with (Human, Person, et al. 2018) and (Human, Random, et al. 2019).
This is a two authors citation (First and Second 2019).
This is an unrelated citation with three authors (Uno et al. 2019).
```

How can I configure BibLaTeX to give me the expected output? I tried several variants of `uniquename` etc. but with no success.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Thanks for adding an MWE!

Comment: There's a warning about conflicting options ...

Comment: @JosephWright I updated the MWE, warning is gone but the issue remains

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69028/35864

Comment: Duplicate? https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/474511/35864

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution by trial-and-error by myself. The combination of `uniquename=mininit` and `uniquelist=minyear` does only show one author and et al. when the year is different, but does add a,b,c etc. when the authors and the year are identical.

So the whole bibtex include is:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,mincitenames=1,maxcitenames=2,giveninits=true,uniquename=mininit,uniquelist=minyear]{biblatex}
```

Maybe this is useful to others having similar trouble.