# How to consistently get 'name 1 et al. (year)' and not also 'name 1, name 2, et al. (year)' in case of multiple references starting with 'name 1'

Tags: biblatex

The text in the following MWE describes the problem. I would like
references with three or more authors to show up as 'name 1 et al. (year)'
but it seems that 'name 1, name 2, et al. (year)' is used if there are
several references with the same first author -- even if the year
already disambiguates the references.

If there's a good reason not to use 'name 1 et al. (year)', I'd also
be interested to know (I'd be fine with 'name 1, name 2, et al. (year)' if
there are two identical 'name 1 et al. (year)' references, so if also the
year is the same).

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[
style=authoryear,
maxnames=2,
maxbibnames=6
]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{bib.bib}
@Book{mcneilfreyembrechts2015,
  author =   {McNeil, A. J. and Frey, R. and Embrechts, P.},
  publisher = {Princeton University Press},
  title =    {Quantitative Risk Management: Concepts, Techniques and Tools},
  edition =  2,
  year =     2015
}

@Book{embrechtsklueppelbergmikosch1997,
  author =   {Embrechts, P. and Kl{\"u}ppelberg, C. and Mikosch, T.},
  publisher = {Springer},
  title =    {Modelling Extremal Events for Insurance and Finance},
  year =     1997
}

@InCollection{embrechtsmcneilstraumann2002,
  author =   {Embrechts, P. and McNeil, A. J. and Straumann, D.},
  editor =   {Dempster, M.},
  title =    {Correlation and Dependency in Risk Management: Properties and
                  Pitfalls},
  booktitle = {Risk Management: Value at Risk and Beyond},
  publisher = {Cambridge University Press},
  pages =    {176--223},
  year =     2002
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}

\begin{document}
All references consist of three authors. The first reference \textcite{mcneilfreyembrechts2015}
shows up as expected.
The reference \textcite{embrechtsklueppelbergmikosch1997} shows up in the form
`name 1, name 2, et al. (year)' and the reference
\textcite{embrechtsmcneilstraumann2002} as well. Why not Embrechts et al. (1997)
and Embrechts et al. (2002)? (the different year already disambiguates the references)
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Specify the biblatex option `[maxcitenames=1]`.

Comment: You want `uniquelist=false,` (or maybe `uniquelist=minyear,` if you want disambiguation for works from the same year): https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69028/35864. While you are at it, also checkout if you want `uniquename`: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134535/35864.

Comment: @moewe: ... `uniquelist=minyear` is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: Would you be OK with closing your question as a duplicate of the standard https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69028/35864 or do you want an answer mentioning `minyear` explicitly?

Comment: Thanks, as `minyear` is not mentioned there, I'd say a separate answer here would be good to have.

Comment: Hah! Finally found a duplicate. What do you think of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/474511/35864?

Comment: ... well spotted, I didn't find that when doing the initial search.