# Biblatex 'minnames=1, maxcitenames=3' doesn't work in Overleaf (same surname/familyname problem)

Tags: biblatex, citing, german

`minnames=1` `maxcitenames=3` doesn't work in Overleaf in the citations and short-form documentation (German: Kurzbeleg). What can I do?

In the following screenshot you can see, it works with one author, two authors and more then three authors. But with three authors it doesn't (here: 'Siddique, Mahmud et. al. 2017' - which should be 'Siddique et al. 2017'):

[image: Auszug]

Here's my Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ext-authoryear-icomp, hyperref=true, uniquename=false, maxcitenames=2, maxbibnames=3, minnames=1, introcite=plain, dashed=false,]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bib/references.bib}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareFieldFormat{bbx@introcite}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}
\UndeclareInnerCiteDelims{bbx@introcite}
\renewcommand*{\introcitepunct}{\quad}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{Siddique.2016} \autocite{Siddique.2017} \autocite{Muller.2018} \autocite{Stiewe.2015} \autocite{he2018thermoelectric} \autocite{He.2017}

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc, title={Literaturverzeichnis}]
\end{document}
```

This are examples from my bib:

```
@article{Siddique.2016,
 author = {Siddique, Abu Raihan Mohammad and Rabari, Ronil and Mahmud, Shohel and {van Heyst}, Bill},
 year = {2016},
 title = {Thermal energy harvesting from the human body using flexible thermoelectric generator (FTEG) fabricated by a dispenser printing technique},
 pages = {1081--1091},
 volume = {115},
 issn = {03605442},
 journal = {Energy},
 doi = {10.1016/j.energy.2016.09.087}
}
@article{Siddique.2017,
 author = {Siddique, Abu Raihan Mohammad and Mahmud, Shohel and {van Heyst}, Bill},
 year = {2017},
 title = {A review of the state of the science on wearable thermoelectric power generators (TEGs) and their existing challenges},
 pages = {730--744},
 volume = {73},
 issn = {13640321},
 journal = {Renewable and Sustainable Energy Reviews},
 doi = {10.1016/j.rser.2017.01.177}
}
@misc{Stiewe.2015,
 author = {M{\"u}ller, Eckhard and Stiewe, Christian},
 year = {2015},
 title = {Anwendungspotential thermoelektrischer Generatoren in station{\"a}ren Systemen Chancen f{\"u}r NRW: Studie im Auftrag des Ministeriums f{\"u}r Innovation, Wissenschaft, Forschung des Landes Nordrhein-Westfalen},
 url = {https://elib.dlr.de/100251/},
 urldate = {2021-02-22},
 editor = {{Deutsches Zentrum für Luft- und Raumfahrt e.V.}},
 institution = {{Institute of Materials Research - Thermoelectric Materials and Systems}}
}
@article{Muller.2018,
 author = {M{\"u}ller, Eckhard and Stiewe, Christian and Ebling, Dirk},
 title = {Anwendungspotential thermoelektrischer Generatoren zur Abw{\"a}rmenutzung in station{\"a}ren Systemen},
 year = {2018},
 pages = {1--11},
 journal = {Gefahrstoffe-Reinhaltung der Luft}
}
@article{he2018thermoelectric,
  title={Thermoelectric properties of silicon and recycled silicon sawing waste},
  author={He, Ran and Heyn, Wieland and Thiel, Felix and P{\'e}rez, Nicol{\'a}s and Damm, Christine and Pohl, Darius and Rellinghaus, Bernd and Reimann, Christian and Beier, Maximilian and Friedrich, Jochen and others},
  journal={Journal of Materiomics},
  volume={5},
  number={1},
  pages={15--33},
  address={Peking},
  year={2018},
  publisher={Chinese Ceramic Society}
}
@article{He.2017,
 author = {He, Jian and Tritt, Terry M.},
 year = {2017},
 title = {Advances in thermoelectric materials research: Looking back and moving forward},
 pages = {1--9},
 volume = {357},
 number = {6358},
 journal = {Science},
 doi = {10.1126/science.aak9997}
}
```

Comment: please make *complete* example. Why should the people who help you constantly have to expand your snippets to a full document?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer is that what you wish? Or did I miss something more?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/moewew/330e6d38e0a3016028ef95d9cfe70244 shows that with the stuff shown so far the problem does not occur: It produces "(He u.a. 2018; Müller u.a. 2018; Siddique u.a. 2017; Sigfridsson und Ryde 1998)".

Comment: Ok, strange. So there must be a problem in Overleaf?

Comment: I don't have your class, but did you actually try your example or do you simply assume that it demonstrates your problem?

Comment: But you are *probably* looking for the `uniquelist` option: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69028/35864.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer sorry I don't get your question. I'm using Overleaf since some days.

Comment: There is a related option called `uniquename` that you may also want to have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134535/35864.

Comment: You show above an example. Did you actually test *exactly* this example? Can you show the output you get from it?

Comment: What Ulrike is saying is that the code you posted has two problems: (1) `wissdoc` does not appear to be a class that is available on CTAN, so other people can see your code, but not actually run it. (2) The code as shown so far will very likely *not* reproduce the problem you are asking about (it definitely does not, if you use `article` instead of `wissdoc`). If you copy it into a new Overleaf project and run it, you will get something like "He u.a. 2018; Müller u.a. 2018; Siddique u.a. 2017". You need to check that the code you post actually reproduces the issue.

Comment: @moewe thanks -  I just realized now, that `wissdoc` is a class I got from somebody, that not everybody has and I changed it to `article`. Now the example should reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yes, it shows the problem now. The solution is `uniquelist=false,` (or possibly `uniquelist=minyear,` see [the `biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) for the difference). Questions like this show how important it is to provide reproducible and compilable example documents (MWEs: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) and not just code snippets. People don't generally ask for these things to annoy you, they ask for these things, because they are the best way to make sure you get the help you want quickly and efficiently.

Comment: For a discussion of `minyear` see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/474511/35864.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer my own question with @moewe's hint.
The problem seems to be, that several authors have the same family name. I found out `uniquename=init` helps, if there are two different authors with the same surname/familyname, but with another given name (It adds the initial of the given name to disambiguating authors).
If there is twice the same author, but the references are from a different year `uniquelist=minyear, labelyear=true` solves the problem.

That would be my solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ext-authoryear-icomp, hyperref=true, uniquename=init, maxcitenames=2, maxbibnames=3, minnames=1, introcite=plain, dashed=false, uniquelist=minyear, labelyear=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bib/references.bib}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareFieldFormat{bbx@introcite}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}
\UndeclareInnerCiteDelims{bbx@introcite}
\renewcommand*{\introcitepunct}{\quad}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{Siddique.2016} \autocite{Siddique.2017} \autocite{Muller.2018} \autocite{Stiewe.2015} \autocite{he2018thermoelectric} \autocite{He.2017}

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc, title={Literaturverzeichnis}]
\end{document}
```

Comment: There is no need for `labelyear=true,` here. `labeldate=true,` is the now deprecated name of `labeldateparts=true,`. But all `authoryear` styles already set `labeldateparts=true,`.

Comment: Also as I remarked earlier, you can drop the `hyperref=true,`, the default `hyperref=auto,` will also link your citations. You should also keep in mind that `hyperref` should usually be loaded last in your preamble. (There are a few exceptions like `cleveref` that need to be loaded after `hyperref`.)