# biblatex: Question about the `maxcitenames` option: `\textcite` uses more names than `maxcitenames` (similar or same author names but different year)

Tags: biblatex

- I am confused :).
- I use the `maxcitename` option of the `biblatex` package but the result in the MWE does not seem to be plausible.
- **Why are so many names used in the `\textcite` output?** I trust that `biblatex` works great and I assume that the problem is me :).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
    style=authoryear-comp,
    maxcitenames = 2, % <--- No effect?
        ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inproceedings{DaLio2014,
address = {Paris , France},
author = {{Da Lio}, Mauro and Biral, Francesco and Bertolazzi, Enrico and Galvani, Marco and Bosetti, Paolo and Saroldi, Andrea and Tango, Fabio},
booktitle = {Transport Research Arena (TRA) 2014 Proceedings},
keywords = {advanced driver assistance systems,co,continuous support,driver,fp7 interactive project,human robot interactions,interactIVe},
month = {04},
title = {{The driver Continuous Support function in the FP7 \enquote{interactIVe} project: an implementation based on the \enquote{co-driver} metaphor}},
url = {https://trid.trb.org/View/1327742},
year = {2014}
}

@article{DaLio2015,
author = {{Da Lio}, Mauro and Biral, Francesco and Bertolazzi, Enrico and Galvani, Marco and Bosetti, Paolo and Windridge, David and Saroldi, Andrea and Tango, Fabio},
doi = {10.1109/TITS.2014.2330199},
issn = {1524-9050},
journal = {IEEE Transactions on Intelligent Transportation Systems},
keywords = {interactIVe},
month = {02},
number = {1},
pages = {244--263},
publisher = {Institute of Electrical and Electronics Engineers Inc.},
title = {{Artificial Co-Drivers as a Universal Enabling Technology for Future Intelligent Vehicles and Transportation Systems}},
volume = {16},
year = {2015}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\section{Option \texttt{maxcitenames = 2} is active}
\begin{description}
\item \textcite{DaLio2014}
\item \textcite{DaLio2015}
\end{description}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: For future readers: BTW, I looked at the linked (duplicate) question. IMHO, a significant difference is that the lockstep's good answer (and the question) shows an example where both references have the same year (2001), whereas in my example the years are different.

Comment: For `uniquelist=true,` and `uniquelist=false,` the year is irrelevant. If you want disambiguation only in the same year, you need `minyear` (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/474511/35864). But as I read the question you want `maxcitenames` to be respected at all times, i.e. you don't want disambiguation in any case.

Comment: @moewe Thanks! Would it be better to link my question to the duplicate that you just mentioned? Not sure how I can do that, maybe reopen first?

Comment: I vote to **reopen** to link to another duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/474511/35864

Comment: Duplicates can be edited without reopnening. I added the other link as well. The question can stay closed.

Comment: Ah, thanks (+1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update by Manuel (OP) after the comment of user moewe:** In my case, the option `uniquelist = minyear` is the one I need because my problem was related to *different years*.

---

biblatex tries to ensure that lists are unique. Use `uniquelist=false` if you don't want that, then you will get (after calling biber again):

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I was confused because the year was different. I will accept asap (not possible atm, need to wait some minutes).